# what is setTimeOut() function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, settimeout

Can i ask what the function of setTimeOut method in javascript?As below:

```
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}
```

Comment: If you want the function to be repeated you probably want to use setInterval instead of repeatedly calling setTimeout yourself - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.setInterval

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure you what you want.

`setTimeout` is a method of the global window object. It executes the given function (or evaluates the given string) after the time given as second parameter passed.

Read more about [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Answer (score 5):

[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.setTimeout) just schedules (sets a timer for) a function to execute at a later time, 500ms in this case. In your specific code, it's updating the screen with the current time every half-second (it only schedules one call, 500ms from now...but *that* `startTime` call scheduled *another*).

Also...passing a string to it when you can avoid it is bad practice, for your example it should be:

```
t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

It schedules your `startTime` function to start again half a second later (500 miliseconds), updating you clock.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeOut` sets a timer and executes the given code after that timer timed out. So using your code, if startTime is called once, it is repeated every half second.

Btw. I assume the delay of 500 ms is used te work around small deviations in the clock. You will want to update the value of the element every whole second. To do that, it is better to calculate the time until the next whole second and set that as a delay. This will give you a more accurate clock.

Answer (score -1):

The `setTimeout()` method allows you to execute a piece of code after a certain amount of time has passed. You can think of the method as a way to set a timer to run JavaScript code at a certain time.

For example, the code below will print "Hello World" to the JavaScript console after 2 seconds have passed:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Hello World");
}, 2000);

console.log("setTimeout() example...");
```

> output:-
>
> - setTimeOut() example...
> - Hello World

---

### OR

---

```
function greeting(){
  console.log("Hello World");
}

setTimeout(greeting, 2000);
```

If you `omit` the second parameter, then `setTimeout()` will immediately execute the passed function without waiting at all.

**You can also pass additional parameters to the `setTimeout()` method.**

```
function greeting(name, city){
  console.log(`Hello, my name is ${name}`);
  console.log(`I live in ${city}`);
}

setTimeout(greeting, 2000, "Milan", "Kathmandu");
```