# HTA open a program and a modal same time

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, hta

Trying to open a program from the PC, using a HTA application while a modal window opens informing the user that the program is loading and please wait.

The problem is the Modal only shows, after I close the launched program?

Tried searching google and stackoverflow without luck

I have no prior experience with java, HTA etc.. So I have build it all with whatever code I could find and LOTS of trial and error

The script to open the modal and close it again after some time.(small problem is that it only works once with the auto close function, then the page needs to reload for it to work again.. easy fixable?)

```java
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }, 5000);

    });
```

The script that enables me to open programs:

```java
    function runApp(which) {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run (which,1,true);
    }
```

This is how my links to open the program and modal looks like:

```
            <a
                href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href"
                id="myBtn"
                onclick="runApp('file://C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe');parent.playSound('assets/sounds/start.mp3');return false;"
                onmouseover="playSound('assets/sounds/hover.wav');"
                unselectable="on"
                style="cursor: hand; display: block;">Link text
            </a>
```

And here is the modal window:

```html
<!-- START: Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal nk-modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title nk-title" id="myModalLabel">Starter program</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Please wait</h4>
                <p>Some text goes here.</p>
            </div>

            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- END: Modal -->
```

So when I click the link to open the program(notepad.exe) then the program opens without problems, but the modal dont show.. When I close Notepad the modal windows opens and then closes after some time.

I want the modal to show, when the link is clicked. So the user knows the computer is working on loading the program and prevent multiple clicks on the link.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to synchronize, but one option would be not wait till app ends (3rd parameter false) and put alert next to .Run:

```
<script>
function runApp(which) {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run (which,1,false);
    alert(which.substr(which.lastIndexOf('/')+1) + " started\nplease wait");
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:runApp('file://C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe')">Notepad</a>
```

Or something like this:

```
<script>
function runApp(which) {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var linksEl = document.getElementById("links");
    var modEl = document.getElementById("modal");
    modEl.innerText = which.substr(which.lastIndexOf('/')+1) + " executed\nWaiting on its exit..."
    linksEl.style.display = "none";
    WshShell.Run (which,1,true);
    modEl.innerText = "";
    linksEl.style.display = "";
}
</script>
<body>
<span id="links">
<a href="#" onclick="runApp('file://C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe')">Notepad</a>
</span>
<span id="modal"></span>
</body>
```

And demo snippet of 2nd variant (even window.open does not work, replaced by alert):

```js
function runApp(which) {
    var linksEl = document.getElementById("links");
    var modEl = document.getElementById("modal");
    modEl.innerText = which.substr(which.lastIndexOf('/')+1) + " executed\nWaiting on its exit..."
    linksEl.style.display = "none";
    alert(which);
    modEl.innerText = "";
    linksEl.style.display = "";
}
```

```html
<span id="links">
<a href="#" onclick="runApp('http://www.google.com')">Notepad</a>
</span>
<span id="modal"></span>
```

Comment: And there is also disabled property of anchor - send this to the function and set thisParameter.disabled=true/false to prevent another click. Mind ticking Accept button under voting in case.

Comment: Awesome thank you Tom..

Of course it was something as simple as a true needed to be false.. 

Now the Modal opens when i click my links.. I had no idea the script is monitor when the launched program closes.. My plan was to keep it simple: have the modal show when the link is clicked then close after like 20 seconds, when I'm sure the program is launched before hiding the modal.

Now I just need to figure out how to fix the problem, with the auto close function only working once then the page needs to reload.. Any ideas?

Comment: Not using jQuery much, JS is single threaded with events, so almost every command block execution by default. What about second version using CSS display and if you do not want to wait till exit of the app, you can use window.setTimeout with predefined time to close the message and enable anchors again. Here answers about this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552826/what-is-settimeout-function-in-javascript#4552858

Comment: I used to have an external wsh-script for searching from a server for some files. When the files were found, the wsh-script wrote the filenames to a textfile, which the main program was reading every two seconds or so. You could use this same technique. Reading a file with ActiveX is really fast, and setting a reading interval of 1 sec or 2 secs can't hardly be detected by the user.